# UIButton does not send action to First Responder

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard

I display controller with a button over another controller. The button is set to send an event to its First Responder.

I handle the the event in my first controller, but nothing is handled, or fired. I tried to handle the event directly in the second controller which work, but this is not the behaviour I want.

The way I instantiate the second Controller in the first one :

```
- (void)viewTapHandler:(id)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueToSecondController" sender: self];
}
```

Here is the handler in my first Controller :

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue
{
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And this is the way I link it in the IB :

[image]

Do you have any clue to resolve this ?

Comment: If your `dismiss:` method's parameter's `UIStoryboardPopoverSegue`, you can't trigger it with a `UIButton`...

Comment: Even with `(id)sender` as parameter, the event is not trigger.